# VBA Autofilter between todays date and todays date - 1 year

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am trying to filter between todays date and todays date minus 1 year.  When I run the below VBA nothing happens and the filter doesn't set. Can anyone point me in the correct direction and have searched forums high and low.

```
Sub Date_Filter()

    Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q

    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    StartDate = Date
    EndDate = Date - 365
    Sheets("Advisor Data").Select
     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AL$10000").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(EndDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(StartDate)

End Sub
```

Comment: Code works for me. Date is really in column 4 and column 4 really contains dates and not text looking like dates? Or maybe code works for you as well and just the data is like that, i.e.just no data between start- and enddate.

Comment: That probably because when you are casting your date as a Double, the value changes to... well Double. In this case 42870 (5/15/17). Is there a value of 42870 in your column "D"?

Comment: Yeah double checked, the Data is in D2:D500 all as 'Date' Format?

Comment: The data goes back to 01/01/17

Comment: What happens if you set the filter manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The year has sometimes 366 days, thus to make your code a bit robust you may use `DateSerial()`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    startDate = Date
    endDate = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, Month(Date), Day(Date))

    Debug.Print endDate

End Sub
```

Once you have the correct `endDate`, the autofilter looks ok.

Comment: The filter now works to an extent, It appears to only be minus filtering a 11month period

Comment: @Fordy - this is strange, are you sure that you have enough data for the 12 months?

Comment: That is correct, it data goes  back to Jan 17 would I need to minus serial month by 13?

Comment: @Fordy - run the code. Then take a look at the printed value. Currently it is `5/15/2017`. `Month-13` would give an error, because it will be negative.

Comment: I have re-run given your code and it now works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Date_Filter()
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    EndDate = Date
    StartDate = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Date)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Advisor Data").Range("$A$1:$AL$10000")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CLng(EndDate)
    End With
End Sub
```